# Whats the best way to debug css on ie?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

in firefox I can usee firebug, in chrome I can use the css console. Both to make live changes to css for troubleshooting purposes. However I do not know of a way to do this in IE, which is where I have the most css issues.

So, whats the best way to troubleshoot css issues in IE?

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the [IE Dev Tools](http://live.visitmix.com/MIX10/Sessions/FT51) (video).

And [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-vista/Internet-Explorer-Developer-Tools-recommended-links) for more links and information.

They are built into IE 8 and can be invoked by <kbd>F12</kbd>.

Answer (score 7):

If you like using Firebug, give [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) a try.

**Edit**: In case it's not clear, Firebug Lite is for any browser. It is created with JavaScript, it is not an extension/plugin.

This makes CSS debugging easy on IE7 and even IE6.

Answer (score 4):

IE Developer tool .. if you are using IE8 .. just hit F12

or

click Tools -> Developer Tools

Answer (score 4):

The most popular for IE is:

**[Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=E59C3964-672D-4511-BB3E-2D5E1DB91038&displaylang=en)**

[image]

Comment: Only for pre-IE8. IE8 has them bundled (and won't load that toolbar anyway).

Comment: @Michael Madsen: Thanks for adding that, I personally don't use that, I am with my development time at firefox and later check in rest of the browsers :)

Answer (score 0):

IE Developer Tools http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565627%28v=VS.85%29.aspx